# Which Scala function to replace this procedural statement?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, procedural

Mindblock here, but I can't figure out how to make this less ugly:

```
def getClosestSphere(ray: Ray, spheres: List[Sphere]): Sphere = {
    val map = new HashMap[Double, Sphere]
    for (sphere <- spheres) {
      val intersectPoint = sphere.intersectRay(ray)
      map.put(intersectPoint, sphere)
    }    
    map.minBy(_._1)._2  
  }
```

Can you see what I'm doing? I have a List of Spheres, where each Sphere has a method intersectRay, returning a double.

I want to take the Sphere with the smallest result of that function. I KNOW there is a nice functional construct to let me do this in one line, I just can't see it :(

Comment: I knew it was easy. 12 hours at the PC will do that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could just do:

```
def getClosestSphere(ray: Ray, spheres: List[Sphere]): Sphere = {
  spheres.minBy(_ intersectRay ray)
}
```

A style tip, as an aside:

When using a mutable collection, use qualified imports. For `java.util.SomeCollection`, first `import java.{util => ju}`, and then use the name `ju.SomeCollection`. For `scala.collection.mutable.SomeCollection`, first `import collection.mutable` and then use the name `mutable.SomeCollection`.

Comment: I will definitely use qualified imports now. I read it in Programming in Scala, but totally forgot

Answer (score 5):

```
spheres.minBy(_.intersectRay(ray))
```